# is there a js library for displaying image search results in rows with optimal spacing?

Tags: javascript, html, image, position

Sites like google image search display images of varying width in rows. Apparently, they select which images to group together, and which images to make a bit smaller, in order to achieve a fairly even spacing between the images.

I tried to search online for a library that implements such an algorithm.

I am asking here if anyone knows of such a solution and if not, I could use some pointers on how to write this code myself.

UPDATE: I found [photowall](http://creotiv.github.io/jquery-photowall/) using jquery.
this seems to be the answer. I am currently searching for an angular.js directive

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the library [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (the one mplugjan also mentioned). This library is very flexible in the way you can set up a grid. [See their options page](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html).

If you want to do it your self, you have roughly two options:

1. The images have a fixed/max width
2. The images have a fixed/max height

Google Images give their images a max height, which allows them to creates rows, and position the images inside them.

The other option is to create columns of a fixed with and place the images in these columns. This option, however is a bit harder to implement, because you have to think harder about the order in which the images are placed.

Edit:
After a quick look at Photowall, it seems that Masonry is more flexible. The documentation on the Masonry site show far more examples in mixing various heights/widths.